# how external app can access ibm cloud object storage

Tags: ibm-cloud, object-storage, ibm-cloud-storage

I have IBM COS service and able to use Curl command via cli to retrieve objects. I used IAM tokens to retrieve. But how do I let an external web app ex., node access this service?

what value should be there in authorization for external app access?

Answer (score 1):

External apps will come in the form of something like the [AWS CLI](https://ibm-public-cos.github.io/crs-docs/cli) or any other app that uses either an HTTP library coupled with [IBM Cloud Object Storage API](https://ibm-public-cos.github.io/crs-docs/about-compatibility-api) or even an SDK for languages like [Python](https://ibm-public-cos.github.io/crs-docs/python), [Java](https://ibm-public-cos.github.io/crs-docs/java) or [Node.Js](https://ibm-public-cos.github.io/crs-docs/node)

All of the above will ask you for **access key** and **secret key**.

You can get both of them from the IBM Cloud console by generating new HMAC Credentials [1]:

1. Navigate to your Cloud Object storage account
2. Click on right under Service credentials
3. Click New credentials button on right
4. For the "Add Inline Configuration Parameters (Optional)" text box enter the following JSON:
   `{"HMAC":true}`

[1] https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/cloud-object-storage/iam/service-credentials.html#service-credentials

Comment: Thanks. I believe using HMAC is optional. In such case, I am still trying to find out how to request IBM COS using api key instead of bearer token because this will have to be used by an external app staying outside of cloud network.

Answer (score 0):

We'll you could use the ibm-cos-sdk Node library https://www.npmjs.com/package/ibm-cos-sdk. You'll need to use your HMAC credentials.

```
var config = {
    endpoint: '<endpoint>',
    ibmAuthEndpoint: 'https://iam.ng.bluemix.net/oidc/token',
    serviceInstanceId: '<resource-instance-id>',
    accessKeyId: '<HMAC access_key>',
    secretAccessKey: '<HMAC secret access key>'
};
```

Comment: Getting an error

 An error occurred:
CredentialsError: Missing credentials in config

Comment: Checked it out. You're going to need your HMAC credentials as well to get it working. I've updated my answer.